# Perl unicode hash key lookup

Tags: perl, unicode

I am so confused by the unicode and unicode in perl.

I got this hash from MySQL db.

```
my $hashFromDB = { "Ves\x{101}kha" => "some value" };
```

But I only know the key in this form of notation

```
my $key = "Ves\u0101kha";
```

How can I convert that \uXXXX notation to that \x{xxx} so that I can get the value with the key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\x{}` escape in Perl works almost exactly like `\u` escape in JS. You simply use code inside `{}`, exactly as in your first snippet:

```
my $key = "Ves\x{101}kha";
my $value = $hashFromDB->{$key};
```

If you have literal string with `\u` in it, which I assume means "\u followed with 4 hexadecimal digits to form codepoint number", just preprocess it with regexp that would replace such sequences with real characters with same code:

```
$key =~ s/\\u([a-fA-F0-9]{4})/chr(hex($1))/ge;
```

BTW, `\u` have different meaning in Perl - it upercases next symbol. You can [check complete list of escapes in documentation](http://p3rl.org/perlrebackslash).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but if I know that key as "Ves\x{101}kha" I would already have no problem. But I only know that in \uXXXX , so the only way is to use regex to convert it to \x{} ? If so is there a library/built in function to do this ? Thanks